# Jquery Select2.js Does Not Work After Migration

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I migrated my form from a file to another with different file location. I also have changed all reference paths on that new file. Unfortunately, the select2() function doesn't work anymore in

```
$("#field1, #field2, #field3").select2();
```

To make sure if the path is right, I have tried to put

```
alert('hello from select2.js');
```

And the alert function works when I open the form. And it makes me confused why the .select2() function does not work.

Did I miss something? Please help and thanks for advance.

Comment: did you miss a closing quote in selector `#field1, #field2, #field3` ?

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot that. But in my real codes, I already put it there. I have edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: Way to little info to answer your question.

Comment: check the console log of your browser, may be there is some error into it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it. After two days. I refered to jquery.js twice. And I don't know why, it really caused the error. After I dismiss one of them, my problem solved. Thanks for everyone who tried to help me :)